# NSURLRequest url ends with a slash

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I've got an issue with image downloading from a server. I'm trying to download an image with an URL like :

```
[HOST]/<path to the image>/3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec/
```

As you can see, the image ends with a slash. When trying to download this image by doing this code :

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"[HOST]/<path to the image>/3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec/"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:imageUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:BkRemoteImageViewDefaultTimeoutInteval];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

The connection fails and launch the protocol method :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

with the error code `404`. My assumption is that the URL loaded is :

```
[HOST]/<path to the image>/3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec
```

(without the last "slash") instead of

```
[HOST]/<path to the image>/3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec/
```

The path without the last slash is not a valid object hence the `404` issue.

I don't know how to correct this. Any idea?

Comment: Does removing the slash from your `initWithString:` call help?

Comment: Well, exclude the slash, in first place?

Comment: Nope doesn't work either

Comment: I would think that status code 404 is correct when you request a particular resource, for example with an id "3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec", and the URL ends with a slash. If that resource maps to a "container" then a trailing "/" _should_ be included. What do you mean with "The path without the last slash is not a valid object" ?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, What I meant is that the resource name is "3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec/", if you're trying to access object named "3cadda28-a334-400b-9d96-8f6dda938dec", then a 404 issue will appear as this is not te right resource name.

Comment: How do you know your "assumption" is correct? Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and change the URL to use `localhost:8000` as the host. See what is actually sent. edit: better commands

Comment: Something that strikes me as weird: you say that `-connection:didFailWithError:` is called with a 404 error, but `NSURLConnection` doesn't do that itself. Have you got some sort of add-on, or is the 404 actually arriving in `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`?

Answer (score 0):

A URL must be properly encoded.

The character "/" is a *reserved* character. The meaning of this reserved character is to separate *path components* from a URL. If the character "/" is *part* of the path, it must be encoded.

In that special case, where the character "/" is part of the URL this character needs to be represented with a sequence of three characters: "%2F".

Other special characters require a different encoding. This URL encoding is also named "Percent-Encoding".

See also:

[wiki Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), 
[webschools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), 
[RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

Comment: You should check whether the URL is actually correct. The character "/" at the and of URL which is not a path separator might have confused others. Check the "routes" on the server, too.

Comment: I tried to load my URL on my Internet Broser by replacing the last '/' by %2F and it loads correctly

Comment: Then :)  Now, you just need to get the URL encoding right on iOS or Mac OS X. There are CF functions in `CFStringRef` and Foundation methods in `NSString` which percent encode a string to a URL.

Comment: You mean stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSString method?